# How to return hierarchy tree from parent to all child elements by LINQ?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, treeview

I have a tree view, and it contains hierarchy with parent item (Manager) and child items (Reporters). The issue that I need to get all child items with different nesting levels, from parent node to child by LINQ.

There is my hierarchy tree node model:

```
public class EmployeeTree
{
    public EmployeeTree()
    {
        Reporters = new List<EmployeeTree>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ManagerId { get; set; } 
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public virtual EmployeeTree Manager { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeTree> Reporters { get; set; }
}
```

First I get the parent item:

```
public EmployeeTree GetEmployeeParent()
    {
        var employee = context.Employees
            .Where(x => x.ManagerId == null)
            .FirstOrDefault();
        GetEmployeeChildTree(employee);
        return employee;
    }
```

Then, I try to get all child elements by recursion, but I have got NullReferenceException cause, I `m did not get child items.

```
private void GetEmployeeChildTree(EmployeeTree employee)
    {
        var employeeReporters = context.Employees
            .Include(x => x.Reporters)
            .Where(x => x.ManagerId == employee.Id).ToList();

        if (employeeReporters.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var reportersNode in employeeReporters)
            {
                GetEmployeeChildTree(reportersNode);
                employee.Reporters.Add(reportersNode);
            }
        }
    }
```

As I understand, I need to use recursion to get all level of child items. Thanks for any advise.

Comment: Here is code I wrote yesterday that works : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55499474/how-to-load-treeview-nodes-from-sqllite-database/55499930#55499930

Comment: Just missing one line : if(employee.Reporters == null) employee.Reporters = new ICollection<EmployeeTree>()
employee.Reporters.Add(reportersNode);

Comment: it does not work on this way, if(employee.Reporters == null) employee.Reporters = new ICollection<EmployeeTree> { employee.Reporters.Add(reportersNode) } I cannot have instance of ICollection

Comment: @jdweng it does not work, I cannot create an instance of interface ICollection, cause i try employee.Reporters = new ICollection<EmployeeTree>()

Comment: A ICollection can be initialized with a List object.  So try this : if(employee.Reporters == null) employee.Reporters = new List<EmployeeTree>();

Comment: @jdweng I tied, but still got NullReferenceException in this section employeeReporters = context.Employees.Include(x => x.Reporters).Where(x => x.ManagerId == employee.Id).ToList();

Comment: Does it work if you remove : .Include(x => x.Reporters)

Comment: @jdweng yes, I`ve tried this

Comment: What were the results?

Comment: sorry, I was the same result NullReferenceException

Comment: The only way you can get the exception is if this instruction returns null : .Where(x => x.ManagerId == null).  Is it possible the root manager ID is zero (or another number) and not null

Comment: I check it, and it have Id in db, thank you, I will investigate deeply

Comment: Is employee null?

Comment: If data is coming from a database you may need to use DBNull.Value instead of null.  They are not the same.

Comment: @jdweng thanks, it helps, with DbNull option, cause before I can have an employee with ManagerId == null, that`s why I `ve got exception.

Comment: make an answer, I will vote for it, thanks